# How do i check if user is logged in angularjs with $routeChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

i'm newbie in angularjs i want to check if my user logged or not via 
 i'm newbie in angularjs i want to check if my user logged or not via 
  via  $routeChangeStart

**Controller**

```
angular.module('crud')
  .controller('SigninCtrl', function ($scope,$location,User,$http) {             


    $scope.signin = function(){

    var data={ email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}


        //console.log(typeof user);

       var user=User.signin(data);
        //console.log(typeof user);
     user.success(function (data) {
                    console.log("token signin",data);
                    var token=data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
                    $location.path("/todo");
               })
               .error(function (data) {
                    //Do whatever is needed
                 console.log(data);

               });  


        }   

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the token in localStorage, put it in a `session cookie`. You can use `$cookies` service by angular for this. On `$routeChangeStart` event, you can check the presence of this cookie nd decide wether user is logged in or not.

Comment: can u put  an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
angular.module('crud', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    /*
     *..validate your token here..
     */
  }
}]);
```